# Latest Magit expands hunks after staging

Tags: magit

With the latest version of Magit (20180410.432) I feel that the staging behavior has somewhat changed. Before, I used to expand the unstaged files in the Status Buffer, then stage the hunks one by one. As hunks dropped into Staged section, they became collapsed – that is, only the name of the file was visible. I got used to this behavior, as it allowed me to treat the Unstaged section as a backlog. Now it is visually confusing whether some hunk is already staged or not when it stays expanded after staging.

Has anything changed in Magit regarding this, or am I imagining things? If the former, is there a way to revert the old behavior locally?

Answer (score 3):

What has changed is that the visibility of a section is being remembered when that section temporarily disappears. For example if you fully expand the unstaged changes for a certain file and then commit that, then that section disappears but Magit remembers that it was expanded. When you then stage a change to that same file, then the section is expanded when it reappears.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any way I can bring back the always-collapsed behavior? Doesn't have to be a configuration option, I can redefine some function if needed.